# JSONProxy At http://jsonp.afeld.me/ Error

Tags: json, jsonp

I am using the following function to get JSON data particular API via JSONP Proxy mentioned above. I want to get the MESSAGE from this API.

```
function callMe() {


            var part1 = 'https://jsonp.afeld.me/?callback=?&url=';
            var part2 = 'http://m.icta.lk/services/railwayservicev2/station/getByID?id=168';
            var url = part1 + part2;

            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                document.getElementById("stName").innerHTML = data.MESSAGE;
            });
        }
```

For the above URL I'm getting a message saying Found 1 Results!. That's OK. Proxy is working fine.

But when this URL is assigned to part2 variable

```
part2 = http://m.icta.lk/services/railwayservicev2/ticket/getPrice?startStationID=184&endStationID=61&lang=en
```

I'm getting a message saying Missing Parameters.

Nothing is wrong with above two URLs. You can check. This works well for the first one, But not for the second one. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `part2` contains query parameters, the JSONP server doesn't know that you're trying to pass the `startStationID=` to it, or through to the other API. The solution here is to encode your `part2`:

```
var url = part1 + encodeURIComponent(part2);
```

which turns all the ampersands (`&`) in `part2` to `%26`.